# The type or namespace name 'Citrusresponse' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

Tags: c#, .net, citrus-pay, citrus-engine

I am working on an ASP.NET website and using Citrus pay framework. I am Getting error on this line in my code:

```
Citrusresponse s = DB.GetCollection<Citrusresponse>().FindOneById(TransID);
```

Here are the total modules that I am using in my code.

```
using MongoDB;
using CitrusPay;
using MongoDB.Bson;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
```

I am struggling since two days find the solution of this but still no bug. I have gone through the community forum and questions here.

If you be great anyone can help me in figuring out this bug.

Let me know if you need more information.

Comment: Shouldnt it be `CitrusResponse`?

Comment: Tried that, still not working. @RomanoZumbé

Comment: Did you change BOTH references to CitrusResponse?

Comment: Hi @RobAnthony, yes I did. It isn't working still.

Comment: @TheL then please update your question with correct type name as suggested by others. Also did you check if you are using lower .NET framework than CitrusPay was buit on? You can not target assemblies targeting higher framework versions into an application with lower framework version.